# UIWebView doesn't show keyboard when focusing on text field on the second load

Tags: ios, uiwebview, keyboard, nsurlrequest

I have a really weird problem with a UIWebView.

I'm using it to login users to several services, 
I open the UIWebView, show a HTML login page, and pressing one of the textfields opens up the keyboard, as it should.

[image]

Afterwards, If i try loading a different login screen in it, pressing the input doesn't show the keyboard for some reason.

[image]

Did any of you ever run into this weird bug ? I tried checking for `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];` like i saw some recommend but it doesnt solve the problem unfortunately :(

This is how i load the UIWebView:

```cpp
[webAuth stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML = \"\";"];
[webAuth loadRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:  [NSURL urlWithString:@"http://whatever"] ]];
```

First line is for clearing the page (tried removing it , it doesnt solve the keyboard problem)

Comment: [self.view endEditing:YES]; to force resign first responder. I don't test this, but you can try

Comment: @NeverBe thanks, but this doesn't anser my question unfortunately, i need to understand why on the second load , the webview doesn't respond when an input text is selected... (keyboard doesnt come up)

Comment: I thought about that but it just sounds like such a dirty workaround ... I'll do that for now. Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem with keyboard not showing, but seems to be iOS Version dependend. I test a form dialog which is being loaded by a UIWebView in iOS 4.3 and iOS 5.0 Simulator and the keyboard appears as expected (when tapping on the input field). But when i test the same in an iOS 5.1 Simulator (and also on a device with that version) it doesn't appear. Do you have any suggestions, what in my case could be the problem? Thx

Comment: I solved it already! I added [window makeKeyAndVisible]; in the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method (as described in here in this forum) and that did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm writing this just in case someone else will ever come across this -
 
It seems what caused the problem was using SVProgressHUD to present a loader while the web pages load. I'm not sure how but when i comment them out everything works as expected.

**Update:** Sam has fixed the SVProgressHUD componenet and now it works with no issues on viewDidLoad

Comment: I had the same problem. Thanks for pointing out SVProgressHUD! Though I think the last version fixed the problem with the use of GCD: https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD

Comment: Yup, Sam fixed it just a couple of days ago.

Comment: Do you buy chance know what the actual cause of this issue was, or have the commit in SVProgresssHUD that fixed it? I am experiencing a similar issue, where when I call loadRequest a second time on a UIWebView, the keyboard no longer displays.

Comment: Nevermind ... this did it for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11869918/cant-show-a-keyboard-on-uiwebview-on-new-project-on-xcode-4-4.

Answer (score 2):

I'm really sorry if I missed something, but I can't reproduce your error. Could you maybe specify your setup in more detail? (I'd rather added this post as a comment, but don't have the reputation for it yet, sorry -.- please feel free to change this answer into a comment)

What I do:

1. I use iOS SDK 5.0 and tried on the iOS5.0 simulator and an iPhone4 with iOS5.0
2. I created a simple view-based app and dragged in a button and a webview into the nib file
3. I call the first website in the `viewDidLoad`, which is the Facebook login

   ```
   - (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     [self.webAuth stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML = \"\";"];
     [self.webAuth loadRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://facebook.com"]]];
   }
   ```
4. I use the aforementioned button to call the second website, Twitter login

   ```
   - (IBAction)showWebsite:(UIButton *)sender {
       [self.webAuth stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML = \"\";"];
       [self.webAuth loadRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://twitter.com/#!/login"]]];
   }
   ```
5. I login on Facebook, then press the button, and tap on any Twitter login input field
6. Everything, including the keyboard, works as intended

Comment: When doing it in a different project it works, I'm still not sure what in my current project causes this. Ill keep looking into it.