# Can't show a keyboard on UIWebView on new project on xCode 4.4

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, uiwebview, keyboard

I have just created a new Single View Application on xCode 4.4. And it was created with .storyboards files (instead xib). Then I have added a UIWebView. And now I can't show a keyboard by the code line:

```
[self.window MakeKeyAndVisible];
```

Because there is no any `window` on ViewController.m. How to force showing a keyboard on UIWebView on this new xCode project template?

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always get the window property from the UIApplicationDelegate object. Since this is a singleton object, you can use:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

There you can reach the window property.